map.js:81 Error during search: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'initialize')
I dont know why Im getting this error. Here is my function that is throwing it:
const handleSearch = async () => {
    if (!searchInput) return;
    setSearching(true);
    

    const credential = new SubscriptionKeyCredential(subscriptionKey);
    console.log("Searching for:", searchInput);
    console.log("Credential:", credential);
    var pipeline = MapsURL.newPipeline(new MapControlCredential(mapRef));
    const searchURL = new SearchURL(pipeline);
    console.log("Credential2:", credential);
    

    try {
      console.log("Searching for:", searchInput);
      const response = await searchURL.searchAddress(Aborter, searchInput).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
      );
      console.log("'Response' type:", typeof(response));
      const results = await response.json();
      console.log("Results:", results);
      if (results && results.length > 0) {
        const coordinates = results[0].position;
        console.log("Coordinates:", coordinates);
        // Optionally, you can update the map view to the search result location
        mapRef.current.setCamera({


I was expecting to get the address information from azure maps API. This is my first time using Azure si im not too sure whats causing it. I put in the location "London"

Looking at your code it appears you are both awaiting the searchAddress request and also using the then method of the promise. These do the same thing, and you should only be using one of these. I've never seen a Promise used both ways in any web app, but not surprised your getting an error as I would expect that cause issues. Looking at your code, I would remove the then code and simply go with the following:
const response = await searchURL.searchAddress(Aborter, searchInput);

That said, it looks like you are using the old Azure Maps Search module that is no longer documented. A new set of client libraries for the Azure maps REST services where released. I recommend following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-ts-rest-sdk
Note, when debugging, the error message likely has a line number for where the error occurred (it might have a whole call stack where you can look through how the error in a referenced library flows back to your code). That can greatly help narrow down where the issue is.
